# Exim filter TLD block is blocking more than just the TLD

Tags: exim, regex, filter

Need to discard emails to and from ending in a specific TLD but having an issue, example of a filter:

```
if first_delivery
and ("$h_to:, $h_cc:" contains ".win$")
or ("$h_from:" contains ".win$")
then
seen finish
endif
```

The problem with this is, it not only matches

user@domain.win

but also

something.**win**test@domain.com

How can we write it so it only affects the TLD itself?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `contains` does not support regular expressions.

Also, you need to properly escape any characters that have special meaning in the exim variable expansion step (such as `$` and `\`) that should remain in the actual comparison step.

(Presumably the reason why your filter matches anything at all, is that the `$` has been interpreted as a non-existant variable and just disappears during the variable expansion step which happens before the string comparison.)

The options that look like they should work are `ends` (string comparison of the end of the string)  and `matches` (regex match).

Eg

```
if $h_from: ends ".win"
```

or

```
if $h_from: matches \\.win\$
```

or (if you want quotation marks, eg if there would be spaces in the expression)

```
if $h_from: matches "\\\\.win\\$"
```

See the section [22. String testing conditions](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-4.90/doc/html/spec_html/filter_ch-exim_filter_files.html) section in the Exim filter manual for details.